# How to activate RequireJS In Play Activator

Tags: javascript, playframework, requirejs, typesafe-activator

I'm using Play-Activator version 2.3.7, and trying to activate RequireJS (rjs). I've followed all the steps in the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/detailedTopics/assets/RequireJS-support.md) (or through [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/RequireJS-support)), but couldn't manage to make it work.

Already was - (plugins.sbt)

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")
```

Added - (build.sbt)

```
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs)
```

What is missing? 
Is there any indicator that the plugin is indeed working right now?

Comment: See http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#add . Note that you will need to change the paths to the ones used by Play (ex: `<script data-main="/path/to/your/js/file/main.js" src="/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>`)

Comment: I am using play-framework, therefore I don't have a require.js file, it is embedded in the framework...

Comment: That's why the src path is `/lib/requirejs/require.js` (that file is provided by the framework)

Comment: Found the file in! /assets/javascripts/require.js

Comment: @Salem Could you please upload a working example? It doesn't work